# Bulk Insert doesn't insert any rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, bulkinsert

I am importing data from CSV files into temp tables before merging them with a "real" table.

For my other tables, this works fine. But for this one particular file and table, nothing seems to happen.

```
CREATE TABLE #ManifestHeader (  
[ROTATIONNUMBER] [nvarchar](12) NOT NULL,
[ROTATIONVERSIONNO] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
[IMONUM] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[VESSELNAME] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
[VOYAGENO] [nvarchar](17) NOT NULL,
[CARRIERCODE] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[CARRIERNAME] [nvarchar](35) NULL,
[ETA] [datetime] NULL,
[ETD] [datetime] NULL,
[ACTUALARRIVALDATE] [datetime] NULL,
[LASTPORTOFCALL] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
[PORTARRIVAL] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
[PORTNEXT] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
[PORTFINAL] [nvarchar](5) NULL,    
[BERTHINGDATE] [datetime] NULL,
[CDRSTARTDATE] [datetime] NULL,
[CDRENDDATE] [datetime] NULL,
[CDRSUBMISSIONDATE] [datetime] NULL,
[NUMOFBOLS] [int] NULL,
)

BULK INSERT #ManifestHeader
FROM 'D:\csvfiles\ManifestHeader.csv'
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = '<,>', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIRSTROW = 2, KEEPIDENTITY );

SELECT * FROM #ManifestHeader;
```

The last select statement returns nothing and no errors are shown.

The CSV file contains thousands of lines. Example lines:

```
ROTATIONNUMBER<,>ROTATIONVERSIONNO<,>IMONUM<,>VESSELNAME<,>VOYAGENO<,>CARRIERCODE<,>CARRIERNAME<,>ETA<,>ETD<,>ACTUALARRIVALDATE<,>LASTPORTOFCALL<,>PORTARRIVAL<,>PORTNEXT<,>PORTFINAL<,>BERTHINGDATE<,>CDRSTARTDATE<,>CDRENDDATE<,>CDRSUBMISSIONDATE<,>NUMOFBOLS
12345678911<,>1<,>VB3BV<,>BLACKSTONE<,>020<,>MUNICA<,>MUNICA<,>2012-05-08 10:32:00<,>2012-05-08 11:32:00<,>2012-05-09 07:15:00<,>SGSIN<,>MZZPZ<,>MZZBW<,>MZZBW<,><,>2012-05-09 07:22:00<,><,>2012-05-09 07:22:26<,>1
12345678912<,>1<,>VB4BV<,>REDSTONE<,>021<,>MUNICA<,>MUNICA<,>2011-11-29 11:48:00<,>2011-11-30 11:48:00<,><,>ZADER<,>MZZPZ<,>ZARCB<,>MZZPZ<,><,><,><,><,>
12345678913<,>1<,>VB5BV<,>BLUESTONE<,>022<,>MUNICA<,>MUNICA<,>2012-05-09 08:00:00<,>2012-05-10 10:39:00<,>2012-05-09 11:11:00<,>ZADER<,>MZZPZ<,>ZARCB<,>ITCVV<,><,>2012-05-09 15:00:00<,><,>2012-05-07 11:14:42<,>1
12345678914<,>1<,>VB6BV<,>GREENSTONE<,>023<,>MUNICA<,>MUNICA<,>2012-05-29 07:00:00<,>2012-05-29 23:00:00<,>2012-05-29 09:12:00<,>LKCMB<,>MZMNC<,>MZMNC<,>SGSIN<,><,>2012-05-29 23:00:00<,>2012-05-30 12:00:00<,>2012-05-29 09:30:33<,>1
```

What could I be missing here?

Comment: Hate to ask the obvious - but has your file got anything in it and if so does anything match your criteria?

Comment: You'll need to give as least 2 lines of your CSV that fails to load.

Comment: The file has contents, and I believe it matches the criteria. Shouldn't it give me an error message otherwise?

Comment: And I have now added sample lines from the CSV.

Comment: This works for me given the code and data you have provided. Might there be some non-printing characters in your source file, or a different row terminator?

Comment: Ed: Really? I just copied and pasted the stuff from above into a new csv file and a new query, and it always returns an empty dataset. What are you running it on?

Comment: @PeterEvjan - SQL 2008 R2 Developer (64 bit)

Comment: Ed: It was the row terminator. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Ed Harper led me in the right direction: the row terminator was wrong.

So when I changed it to

```
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
```

in BULK INSERT (instead of '\n') it started working.

Comment: My servers were recently migrated from SQL Server 2005 to 2012. But YESTERDAY it worked with \n and TODAY it only works with 0x0a. What is happening here, actually?

Comment: I think there's some strange interplay between having an integer be the last column type, and needing to specify the row terminator in this way...